# Having a difficulty in positioning element in html

Tags: html, css

I'm positioning the elements absolutely in % from top and left and giving the dimension in % but when I re-size the window the elements move over each other.

Just wondering if to use jQuery to position things or to use any other way? Here is a fiddle [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ankitladhania/tLDyu/)

```
   .the_club_photo
 {
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:40%;
top:60px;
left:0px;
background-color:#fff;
overflow:hidden;
 }
  .question_container
  {
position:absolute;
top:47%;
left:0px;
height:30%;
width:80%;
background-color:#2a2a2a;
  }


 .search_ur_club_container
{
position:absolute;
top:47%;
left:80%;
height:;
width:;
margin:auto 3px;
background-color:#2a2a2a;
}
```

Comment: some code or fiddle pls?

Comment: Your question is very broad and without much detail is likely to be closed. Post some code. Absolutely positioned elements using Percentages will always move over each other eventually.

Comment: then how to position it so that they dont move over each other

Comment: +1 for improving question. Working on an answer without absolute positioned div's.

Comment: BTW Ankit , you can add your link by ( Ctrl + L ) , no need to use `<a>` tag :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is close to what you were trying to achieve. If something doesn't look how you meant, let me know.

http://jsfiddle.net/FhuMt/

HTML:

```
<div class="topSpacer"></div>
<div class="header">
    <div class="headerbg"></div>  
</div>
<div class="body">
    <div class="content">
    </div>
    <div class="navigation">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-family: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background-color:#1a1a1a;
}

.topSpacer {
    height: 60px;
}

.header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 25%;
}
.headerbg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Q4xE6-3pFqo/UToBOlRN3JI/AAAAAAAAADw/Jh8H293L_bo/s1600/Manchester+United2.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}

.body {

}

.content {
    width: 75%;
    background-color: #2a2a2a;
    float: left;
    min-height: 300px;
}

.navigation {
    width: 20%;
    margin-left: 5px;
    background-color: #2a2a2a;
    float: left;
    min-height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: hey are you sure that the way you used the body element, it's legit cause when u apply border of 1px it shows that the body is having no height so what to do

Comment: You'll need to add a clear element after the .body div. You can do that with another `div` or a `br`. Example: `<br style="clear: both;" />`